# Could not understand error message when converting code from C to C++

Tags: c++, c

I am converting a c program into c++, and I encountered these error message:

```
error on line 57:
error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘socklen_t*’
error: initializing argument 3 of ‘int accept(int, sockaddr*, socklen_t*)’
```

My code at line 57 is:

```
connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&sin_size);
```

i am not sure if this information is enough for your guys to figure out. The total no of codes is few hundreds, should I paste it here?

Additional information:

I am doing socket programming in linux environment

Thanks to Andreas Brinck

There is no code line 57 error. But now, I got this:

```
warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used.
/tmp/ccBDefaZ.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

EDIT Second time:

I could ignore the warning, but the:

```
/tmp/ccBDefaZ.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What does it mean? Can it be fixed?

Problem solved.

Previously, I use gcc to compile, then I got the error message, when I switch to g++, the error messages are gone. Thank you guys =)

Comment: If you are actually converting `C` code to `C++`, don't forget to convert the C-style cast to `C++` cast as well (`static_cast`, `const_cast` and so on)

Comment: Its same topic, and I got the first error message solved, but the new error messages appear, should I post in new question, or continue here? Please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
connected = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, (socklen_t*)&sin_size);
```

`sin_size` is obviously an `int` and `accept` expects a `socklen_t*`.

Comment: This is not safe.  ctocpp, you should fix the source variable, as suggested by trojanfoe.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Casting worked and yes you can fix the source variable.

Answer (score 2):

Convert sin_size to type socklen_t:

```
socklen_t sin_size = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

`sin_size` is probably defined as an `int`. However, `accept` requires a `socklen_t *`. That's the interpretation of the error.

You *may* be able to get away by casting. But try using a `socklen_t` instead, for `sin_size`.

C++ is rather more fussy with types.

Answer (score 0):

From this error I can deduce that the socklen_t type is different than the int type. And your function accept expects the pointer of socklen_t type. Either change the signature of accept to make it similar to int or if you are sure that socklen_t will never be different than int(long int, or unsigned int etc.), then use proper cast while passing it to accept.

Answer (score 0):

About the "warning: the 'gets' function is dangerous and should not be used."

It appears that gets() is being "deprecated"... It is actually 'dangerous' because it allows yout to read more data than you have room allocated.

Use fgets instead, it should be fine. fgets() works like

```
fgets(array, array_length, filestream);
```

In other words, a string to fill, its length and the file from where the data must come from. To substitude gets(), the file is `stdin`, the standard input file.

Hope it helps.